# How to create .dll or .lib from multiple c source and header files in visual studio?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

I have C source files and header files from the first version(1.0) of Sundials numerical solver.

https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials

In the makefile information for IDA solver, it looks like this.

```
# File Makefile.idas  Version of 16 December 1999

# Makefile for the serial version of the IDA package

# Notes on machine and environment dependencies:
#
# (1) Files from the IDA solver are accessed as follows:
#     (a) All IDA header files needed are assumed to be in the
#         directory given by IDAINC below.
#     (b) The IDA library file is given by IDALIB below.
#
# (2) The C compiler is given by CC below.
#
# Change these variables as needed for other environments.


IDAINC = ../include
IDALIB = ../lib/libidas.a

CC = cc

# Source files:

CODES = ida.c llnlmath.c idaspgmr.c spgmr.c iterativ.c idadense.c dense.c \
        idaband.c band.c nvector.c

# Object files:

OBJS =  ida.o llnlmath.o idaspgmr.o spgmr.o iterativ.o idadense.o dense.o \
        idaband.o band.o nvector.o


# Command sequence:
# Note that the proper versions of the files nvector.c and nvector.h are
# copied into the proper directories for the compile, then removed.

all:
    cp ./serial/nvector.c nvector.c
    cp $(IDAINC)/serial/nvector.h $(IDAINC)/nvector.h
    $(CC) -c $(CODES) -I$(IDAINC)
    ar rcv $(IDALIB) $(OBJS)
    rm -f *.o
    rm $(IDAINC)/nvector.h
    rm ./nvector.c
```

To me, the unix command simply compiles all the source codes and then link all the objective files into library file *.a in unix.

I would like to do the same thing in Windows 10 and visual studio (2019) or any other window C software to make a static library, *.lib. Can you help me how to do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Create a console application and choose Static library.  If you can work it out from there then we can close this otherwise I'll have to write you a step by step guide which will take a lot longer.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the instruction in the answer below. I was able to create *.lib by adding all the source codes and header files in the project and building solution. By the way I didn't make any new class file (opposed to what is described in the link below) since I have all c source file and header file already. Is this right way to do it ?

Comment: If you have all the source files locally, and the library was created and tested and it worked, then I would say, yes, that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I would like to do the same thing in Windows 10 and visual studio (2019)..."*

Here are example steps using Visual Studio 2019:

Note, because Visual Studios is by definition an IDE, it removes much of the the responsibility from the developer to know as much about make-files and command line-compile instructions.  These things are done within the Visual Studios application via menus and buttons on a GUI.

- On the menu bar, choose File > New > Project to open the Create a New Project dialog box.
- At the top of the dialog, set Language to C++ *[or C]*, set Platform to Windows, and set Project type to Library.
- From the filtered list of project types, select *[Console App]*, then choose Next.
- In the Configure your new project page, enter some *[Name]* in the Project name box to specify a name for the project. Enter *[StaticNameLib]* in the Solution name box. Choose the Create button to open the Windows Desktop Project dialog.
- In the Windows Desktop Project dialog, under Application type, select Static Library (.lib).
- Under Additional options, uncheck the Precompiled header check box if it's checked. Check the Empty project box.
- Choose OK to create the project.

Note:  Content within italicized square brackets ( *[...]* ) is mine.  See *link below* for original.

[*link below*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thank you. I saw the instruction in the link. Is it the same way if I want to add header files and source files to the project , and build them all?

Comment: @Derik - Yes. In fact,  that important step was one thing that this article _did not explicitly include, but of course adding source content i.e. .c, .h etc to the project is a step that is obviously required _before_ attempting to build them into a library.

Comment: @ryyker- I successfully built the library file and tested it in c code. It works !! Thank you.